# DeserializeObject a json into a dictionary and fill in the keys with the PK and the values as ExecutionTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serialization, service

This is the model I am receiving from an API.

```
        var query = FindBy(item => item.TaskEnabledStatus == trueOrFalse).Select(items => new MainGridDto()
        {
            PK_Task = items.PK_Task,
            TaskName = items.TaskName,
            TaskDescription = items.TaskDescription,
            TaskEnabledStatus = items.TaskEnabledStatus,
            BusinessName = items.tBusinessGroups.BusinessName,
            ExecutionTime = items.ExecutionTime.Value,
            BusinessGroupDto = new BusinessGroupDto()
            {
                PK_BusinessGroup = items.tBusinessGroups.PK_BusinessGroup,
                BusinessName = items.tBusinessGroups.BusinessName,
                BusinessGroupEnabledStatus = items.tBusinessGroups.BusinessGroupEnabledStatus
            },
            EmailBody = items.EmailBody,
            EmailSubject = items.EmailSubject,
            UserOwner = items.tUsers.tRecipients.FirstName + " " + items.tUsers.tRecipients.LastName,
            UsersDto = new UsersDto()
            {
                PK_User = items.tUsers.PK_User,
                UserName = items.tUsers.UserName,
                FirstAndLast = items.tUsers.tRecipients.FirstName + " " + items.tUsers.tRecipients.LastName
            },
            UserLastModified = items.tUsers.UserName,
            Frequency = items.Frequency,
            LastModifiedOn = items.LastModifiedOn
        });
```

What I am trying to do is Deserialize the Object into a dictionary, but I keep getting an error because my keys are null. How can I assigned the PK to the dictionary and ExecutionTime as the value. Or even assigning an index to the keys and the object as the value? I had it working with a List, but I wanted to change it to a dictionary to have more efficient searching and performance.

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, ReportInfoDto>>(dtoResponse.Result);
```

An additional note, I am searching the dictionary with a linq query. Is that good practice or is there a more effiecent way?

```
var itemsToSendOut = from reports in model
  where reports.Value.ExecutionTimeFormatted  == DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt ")
  select reports;
```

This is how I am calling the API and getting a json reponse with a list of objects.

```
private HttpClient client;
client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57595/");
var getAllReports = client.GetAsync("api/AllReports").Result;
    if (getAllReports.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    var dtoResponse = getAllReports.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    dtoResponse.Wait();
                    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, ReportInfoDto>>(dtoResponse.Result, new KeyValuePairConverter());

                    var itemsToSendOut = from reports in model
                                         where reports.Value.ExecutionTimeFormatted  == DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt ")
                                         select reports;
```

This is an example data and exact format that the result is giving me when I debug.

```
Result = "[{\"PK_Task\":3,\"TaskName\":\"ExampleReportName\",\"BusinessName\":\"ExampleBusinessName\",\"UserOwner\":\"Stack Leet\",\"UsersDto\":{\"PK_User\":123,UserName\":\"Stack.L   ...
```

Comment: Help me understand why you want to do this: `What I am trying to do is Deserialize the Object into a dictionary`. You said, `I had it working with a List, but I wanted to change it to a dictionary to have more efficient searching and performance.` ..  were you running into performance issues with the list?  It seems to me that you are trying to use a Dictionary in a way that it isn't intended to be used.

Comment: So, I am probably doing a crappy way of implementing this, but I am creating a window service that is going to call an api every minute to get all the reports. Then, I am trying to check each report and look at their ExecutionTime and if it matches the machine current time. I am going to send an email with the report to some recipients. So, I am going to constantly be searching through the dictionary and my thinking is that instead of using a List and going one by one I can use a dictionary and search by the value let's say 12:00 AM and I will get all the reports that need to be sent out at 12

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. So... When you call the API, do you get back a single object? Or a list of objects?  I ask because I'm wondering why you don't just create a `Dictionary<DateTime, Object>` and then add your objects using `.Add` instead of trying to Deserialize.

Comment: Before I attempt an answer, I need some clarification. What exactly is `dtoResponse.Result`?  Is it a single object? Or a list of objects?

Comment: So the reponse from the API I am getting an Http reponse which from what I can tell, needs to be serialized in order to be used.(I'll update my question with how I am calling the api and how I am recieving it) I can serialize to a list and then convert it a dictionary. However, I thought there might be a way to do it with a dictionary instead.

Comment: Ok, so basically, you have a JSON string that you need to work with. Understood. But I'm still wondering if the JSON string contains a single object, or list of objects.

Comment: I just updated my question with the data that I am recieving from the result which looks like a string of objects. Also, in the begining of my question I have the exact model that the API is sending back.

Comment: Ok, perfect.  The `[` in the json tells us you aere getting back a list of objects and not a single object. That's what I was wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your example, if I am hearing you right when you say in your comment: `I am trying to check each report and look at their ExecutionTime`, it sounds like what you want is a:

```
Dictonary<DateTime, MyObject>
```

Where `YourObject` is a single instance from the `List<>` you are getting from the API.  And what you would like to do is extract `ExecutionTime` from the object and use it as the Key in the Dictionary.

Have I got that right? I'm going to answer under that assumption. Let me know if I'm wrong.

As far as I know, I don't think there is a way to deserialize a JSON string to a Dictionary and to specify which property becomes the dictionary's key. *I could be wrong!* And if I am, I hope someone will tell me and provide a better answer. But so far, I've not seen a way to make this happen.

That being said, how I would do it is something like this:

```
// Convert the json string from the API to a List:
List<MyObject> myObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(dtoResponse.Result);

// Loop over list and make a Dictionary
Dictonary<DateTime, MyObject> model = new Dictonary<DateTime, MyObject>()
foreach (MyObject myObject in myObjects)
{
    if (myObject.ExecutionTime != null)
        model.Add(myObject.ExecutionTime, myObject);
}
```

Again, ***IF*** there is a way to do all of that in a single `DeserializeObject<Dictionary...>` line, I'd love to know about it. I looked and didn't see it documented anywhere. But this will get you your Dictionary that you can then quickly and easily search by ExecutionTime.

*(As a side note: this assumes that each `ExecutionTime` is unique. If they are not, it won't work.)*

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

You asked:

> An additional note, I am searching the dictionary with a linq query. Is that good practice or is there a more effiecent way?

```
var itemsToSendOut = from reports in model
  where reports.Value.ExecutionTimeFormatted  == DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt ")
  select reports;
```

Searching a dictionary by something in the value really negates the speed that a dictionary otherwise provides.  If this is what you want, then there is no need for the dictionary at all.  The speed of a dictionary comes because you can search for the value by the key. So you can do an O(1) search. Whereas if you are searching a list (or a Dictionary by it's value) then you are doing an O(n) search where n is the count of items in the list or dictionary.

Comment: Yea, I tried searching a l lot as well for an answer but this will definetelly work! Thank you a lot for working this with me Casey.

Comment: Happy to help! If you don't mind... don't forget to mark this as the correct answer (if it is)